# Repeating the definite article in a list

Tags: grammar, articles

Should there be separate "the" for Barons, King and Queen in the following sentence?

> 1) He provided the bone of contention among the Barons, King and Queen.
>
> 2) He provided the bone of contention among the Barons, the King and the Queen.

Comment: what is the source of these sentences? Please give the context and original source.

Answer (score 1):

I'm **not** commenting on the sentence structure as *providing the bone of contention among someone* is something that I have not come across until now.

But yes, to address the *main question,* no, you don't need to put the definite article with all those objects. Why? Because the article is considered *distributed* across the elements.